# PhP SQL handling an 'Add More' option on a form

Tags: php, sql, form-processing

If I have a form that a user can optionally add extra fields, I am confused on how I should process that. For example

HTML

```
<input name="provider_name" type="text" />
<button class="add-more">Add Provider</button>
```

Javascript / jQ

```
var addtlCounter = 0;
$(".add-more").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  addtlCounter++;
  $(this).before('<input name="provider_name_' + addtlCounter + '" type="text" />');
})
```

Obviously, if there were just ONE provider_name I can just

`INSERT INTO MyTable(value) VALUES ($_POST["provider_name"])`

But depending on how many times the user clicks add a provider, I will get an unknown number of `provider_name_*`.

Any suggestions on when I go to process this form, I can tell how many additional providers they have added and INSERT accordingly.

Comment: be careful inserting $_POST data, you probably want to sanitize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML arrays.

```
<input name="provider_name[]" type="text" />
<button class="add-more">Add Provider</button>
```

Then, in your PHP.

```
foreach($_POST["provider_name"] as $provider)
{
    echo $provider;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

To have two related fields, you can have an array inside an array, but the names must be indexed. As such:

```
  <input name="providers[1][name]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[1][number]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[2][name]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[2][number]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[3][name]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[3][number]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[4][name]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[4][number]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[5][name]" type="text" />
  <input name="providers[5][number]" type="text" />
```

This would result in this array:

```
array(1) {
  ["providers"]=>
  array(5) {
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["number"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["number"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["number"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["number"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["number"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I have multiple fields, such as `provider_name` and `provider_number` that both relate to each other and they can add another row of both those fields??